# Oozie 4.2.0 build failure with Hadoop 1.2.1

Tags: maven, hadoop, oozie

CDH 4.1.1 VM , Java 1.6 , Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.1.1

I am having no knowledge about Java or Maven and I am completely new to this world of Build with Maven. I was exploring Oozie and wanted to build it , but every time I try to build it , it fails with the below error. I have search blogs and known blogs (people have mentioned gauravkohli blog, but that doesn't help me either) without much help. Can anyone help me out here?

```
    [INFO] Building Apache Oozie Docs 4.2.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ oozie-docs ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/training/oozie-4.2.0/docs/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:process (default) @ oozie-docs ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ oozie-docs ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/training/oozie-4.2.0/docs/src/main/resources
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ oozie-docs ---
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/training/oozie-4.2.0/docs/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ oozie-docs ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/training/oozie-4.2.0/docs/src/test/resources
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ oozie-docs ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.2:test (default-test) @ oozie-docs ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:2.0-beta-6:site (default) @ oozie-docs ---
[INFO] Unable to load parent project from a relative path: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model
[FATAL] Non-readable POM /home/training/oozie-4.2.0/../pom.xml: /home/training/oozie-4.2.0/../pom.xml (No such file or directory) @ 
 for project  at /home/training/oozie-4.2.0/../pom.xml for project  at /home/training/oozie-4.2.0/../pom.xml
[INFO] Parent project loaded from repository.
Downloading: https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/apache/16/apache-16-site_en.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Oozie Main ................................. SUCCESS [1.436s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Utils ......................... SUCCESS [0.820s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp 1.2.1 .................. SUCCESS [0.131s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Auth 1.2.1 .................... SUCCESS [0.293s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Libs .......................... SUCCESS [0.031s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Client ............................... SUCCESS [1:10.182s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Oozie ...................... SUCCESS [1.874s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib HCatalog ................... SUCCESS [2.498s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Distcp ..................... SUCCESS [0.935s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Core ................................. SUCCESS [42.904s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Streaming .................. SUCCESS [2.509s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Pig ........................ SUCCESS [2.490s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Hive ....................... SUCCESS [4.022s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Hive 2 ..................... SUCCESS [5.336s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Sqoop ...................... SUCCESS [2.838s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Examples ............................. SUCCESS [11.110s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Spark ...................... SUCCESS [7.669s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib ............................ SUCCESS [16.624s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Docs ................................. FAILURE [3.007s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie WebApp ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Tools ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie MiniOozie ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Distro ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie ZooKeeper Security Tests ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2:57.982s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed May 25 22:27:34 EDT 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 214M/243M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:2.0-beta-6:site (default) on project oozie-docs: The site descriptor cannot be resolved from the repository: Could not transfer artifact org.apache:apache:xml:site_en:16 from/to apache.snapshots.repo (https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots): java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
[ERROR] org.apache:apache:xml:16
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
[ERROR] central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR] apache.snapshots.repo (https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots, releases=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR] datanucleus (http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false),
[ERROR] apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots, releases=false, snapshots=true): Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :oozie-docs

ERROR, Oozie distro creation failed
```

pom.xml

Added part of pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.apache</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache</artifactId>
    <version>17</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.apache.oozie</groupId>
<artifactId>oozie-main</artifactId>
<version>4.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<description>Apache Oozie Main</description>
<name>Apache Oozie Main</name>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
        <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
    </license>
</licenses>

<organization>
    <name>Apache Software Foundation</name>
    <url>http://www.apache.org</url>
</organization>

<properties>
    <targetJavaVersion>1.6</targetJavaVersion>

    <distMgmtSnapshotsName>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</distMgmtSnapshotsName>
    <distMgmtSnapshotsUrl>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots</distMgmtSnapshotsUrl>

    <!-- to be able to run a single test case from the main project -->
    <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>

    <test.timeout>5400</test.timeout>

    <!-- platform encoding override -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <test.exclude>_</test.exclude>
    <test.exclude.pattern>_</test.exclude.pattern>

    <oozie.test.dir>${project.build.directory}/test-data</oozie.test.dir>
    <oozie.test.forkMode>once</oozie.test.forkMode>

    <maven.test.redirectTestOutputToFile>true</maven.test.redirectTestOutputToFile>
    <maven.test.java.opts>-Xmx1024m -da -XX:MaxPermSize=512m</maven.test.java.opts>
    <maven.javadoc.opts></maven.javadoc.opts>

    <oozie.data.dir>${oozie.test.dir}</oozie.data.dir>
    <oozie.test.db.host>localhost</oozie.test.db.host>
    <oozie.test.db>hsqldb</oozie.test.db>
    <oozie.test.default.config.file>${basedir}/src/test/resources/${oozie.test.db}-oozie-site.xml
    </oozie.test.default.config.file>
    <oozie.test.config.file>${oozie.test.default.config.file}</oozie.test.config.file>

    <hadoop.version>1.2.1</hadoop.version>
    <hadoop.majorversion>1</hadoop.majorversion>
    <hadooplib.version>hadoop-${hadoop.majorversion}-${project.version}</hadooplib.version>
    <oozie.hadoop-utils.version>hadoop-${hadoop.majorversion}-${project.version}</oozie.hadoop-utils.version>
    <hbase.version>0.94.27</hbase.version>

    <dropwizard.metrics.version>3.1.0</dropwizard.metrics.version>

    <clover.license>/home/jenkins/tools/clover/latest/lib/clover.license</clover.license>

     <!-- Sharelib component versions -->
     <hive.version>0.13.1</hive.version>
     <pig.version>0.12.1</pig.version>
     <pig.classifier></pig.classifier>
     <sqoop.version>1.4.3</sqoop.version>
     <spark.version>1.1.0</spark.version>
     <spark.guava.version>14.0.1</spark.guava.version>
     <sqoop.classifier>hadoop100</sqoop.classifier>
     <streaming.version>${hadoop.version}</streaming.version>
     <distcp.version>${hadoop.version}</distcp.version>
     <hadoop.auth.version>${hadoop.version}</hadoop.auth.version>

     <!-- Tomcat version -->
     <tomcat.version>6.0.44</tomcat.version>

     <openjpa.version>2.2.2</openjpa.version>
     <xerces.version>2.10.0</xerces.version>
     <curator.version>2.5.0</curator.version>
     <jackson.version>1.8.8</jackson.version>
     <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
</properties>

<modules>
    <module>hadooplibs</module>
    <module>client</module>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>sharelib</module>
    <module>webapp</module>
    <module>examples</module>
    <module>docs</module>
    <module>tools</module>
    <module>minitest</module>
    <module>distro</module>
    <module>zookeeper-security-tests</module>
</modules>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>apache.snapshots.repo</id>
        <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots</url>
        <name>Apache Snapshots Repository</name>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>repository.cloudera.com</id>
        <name>repository.cloudera.com-releases</name>
        <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/ext-release-local</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think adding link for your POM on gist would be more helpful. Looks like a dependency issue.

Comment: Added part of pom.xml